# orderby certain property - code improvement

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have a method like this:

```
public void DoSomething( .... , bool orderByX)
{

    if(orderByX)
    {
       foreach( ... OrderBy(x => x.Location.X))
       {
          ...
       }
    }
    else
    {
       foreach( ... OrderBy(x => x.Location.Y)
       {
          ...
       }
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid the if to produce less repetitive code (i.e. just one foreach). Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A better approach, is to pass criteria, by which to order. You can use next code as motivation:

```
public void DoSomething<T>( .... , Func<Point, T> orderbySelector)
{
    foreach( ... OrderBy(p => orderbySelector(p.Location)))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can:

```
DoSomething(mySequence, point => point.X)
```

or

```
DoSomething(mySequence, point => point.Y)
```

Note: you can generalize selector as much as you want (for instance passing holder or `Location`, instead of `Point` itself).

Also, passing `bool` as ordering criteria makes code less readable. For example I have no clue what this method does, by simply looking at it's call `DoSomething(list, false)` and I have to see method signature in order to know what are the semantics of `false`. It would be much better to use named parameters `DoSomething(list, orderByX : false)` (available from **C# 4.0**), but **if I'm not ordering by `X`, how do I know, that I'm then ordering by `Y`?**. This also limits calling code only to two sorting criteria (you wouldn't want to add another sorting flag, wouldn't you?)

So you need to open your intention making `DoSomething` name revealing, that you in fact ordering your processing. For example `TraverseNodesOrderedBy(nodes, point => point.X)`

Answer (score 3):

Check `orderByX` in the lambda expression for `OrderBy`

```
public void DoSomething( .... , bool orderByX)
{
    foreach( ... OrderBy(x => orderByX ? x.Location.X : x.Location.Y))
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ queries are composable, which means you can build them before they get executed:

```
public void DoSomething( .... , bool orderByX)
{
    var query = ... ;

    if (orderByX)
        query = ... .OrderBy(x => x.Location.X);
    else
        query = ... .OrderBy(x => x.Location.Y);

    foreach(var x in query) // deferred execution
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Just another option besides the other viable answers.